# Properties of the embedding of a vector space into its complexification

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ V $ be a vector space over the real numbers. In this question, its *complexification* is any complex vector space $ V_{\mathbb C} $ equipped with an $ \mathbb R $-linear map $ \iota\colon V\hookrightarrow V_{\mathbb C} $ such that the following universal property holds: for every complex vector space $ W $ and for every $ \mathbb R $-linear map $ \phi\colon V\to W $, there exists a unique $ \mathbb C $-linear map $ \tilde\phi\colon V_{\mathbb C}\to W $ such that the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
V @>\iota>> V_{\mathbb C}\\
@| @VV\tilde\phi V \\
V @>>\phi> W
\end{CD}
$$
commutes.

I'm trying to show that the following two desirable properties of the embedding $ \iota\colon V\to V_{\mathbb C} $ hold:

1. $ \iota $ is injective;
2. if $ \iota(v_1) = i\iota(v_2) $ for some $ v_1,v_2 $ then $ \iota(v_1) = \iota(v_2) = 0 $.

I don't know how to do it by appealing only to the universal property of $ (V_{\mathbb C},\iota) $.

Comment: What is the definition of $F$？

Comment: Whops, it's a typo. Edited.

Comment: Offhand, I'd start by considering the complex vector space $W = V \otimes \mathbf{C}$ (tensored over the reals).

Comment: Yeah it's just an easy check if you're working with an explicit construction (like $ \mathbb C\otimes_{\mathbb R} V $ or $ V\oplus V $). I was wondering if it's possible to prove 1. and 2. using the universal property alone.

Comment: If it matters, the suggestion is not to define the complexification by tensoring with the reals, but to see what the universal property says for a "well-chosen" complex vector space $W$. (If I misunderstood the previous comment, however, please ignore this one.)

Comment: So, $ W = \mathbb C\otimes_{\mathbb R} V $ comes with an _injective_ $ \mathbb R $-linear map $ i\colon V\to W $, and the universal property allows us to factor $ i $ through $ \iota\colon V\to V_{\mathbb C} $. This proves that $ \iota $ is injective.

Comment: Now, I can prove that 2. holds if $ v_1 $ and $ v_2 $ are linearly dependent. If they are not, we can extend $ \{v_1,v_2\} $ to a whole basis of $ V $, and there's a well defined $ \mathbb R $ -linear map $ \phi\colon V\to \mathbb C\otimes_{\mathbb R} V $ sending $ v_1\mapsto 1\otimes v_1 $ and $ v_2\mapsto i(1\otimes v_2) $. Then the universal property tells us that $ 1\otimes v_1 = i(1\otimes v_2) $. But why the thesis follows from this? If instead I pick $ W = V\oplus V $ everything becomes simple.

Comment: Above I probably should use the fact that the $ 1\otimes v_j $ (where the $ v_j $s come from the basis of $ V $ obtained by extending $ \{v_1,v_2\} $) are a basis of $ \mathbb C\otimes_{\mathbb R} V $.